# Why is there such a dislike for the Alien Prequels?

Tags: horror, alien-franchise

The prequels have great depth compared to the original Alien. Themes of creationism, where we came from, where the alien came from and why the virus was created to destroy us. The original alien films imo arent very deep . It's basically just a cat and mouse game on a space ship which dont get me wrong it is thrilling and do like them ( just not as much as the new ones).

Alien covenant has great visuals. In my opinion Alien Covenant is the only movie in the series that shows the true ferocity and evilness of the xenomorph. Which is something that the original movies could not do because the technology was not there. I would think that this alone would make the film so appealing. I mean the cgi IS SOO GOOD. It looks so real. It really drew me in. (Except for the last scene where captain Daniel's is hanging on a rope while trying to kill the xenomorph on the outside of the ship, that was terrible, so obvious it was a blue screen).

All in all I think there were more positives than negatives but it seems like most people dont share the same sentiments and I dont see why?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I know this is a very subjective question and so will be the answer -- but if this is okay here:

Seems the depth is sort of the problem in the prequels -- Alien was so *pure*, no big themes, nothing to not make sense or "religious messagey" where Prometheus seems to be undertaking something huge and it did not do a great job of explaining. I also have read that the idea at one point was that Christ was an Engineer and they crucified him but Sir Ridley felt this was a bit too much "on the nose." Yeah, it sure was. So Prometheus maybe has some thematic problems as well as inconsistencies and poor execution in parts.

Covenant also seems to have religion thrown in for no good reason -- if you watch some deleted scenes there was even more of it. And then there were the amazingly dumb astronauts, etc.

Anyway, big themes leave a lot more room for mistakes and also, prequels come along when the original may be losing steam -- maybe we are about done with the Alien franchise. (But I would still like to see a flick that brought Blade Runner and Alien together somehow -- make it a smaller film is my advice.)